# Replace to entity tags to IOB format

Tags: python-3.x, regex, text-parsing, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to convert non-IOB tags to IOB in a conllu file.

Two sample lines of the file would be:

> 2 Ute Ute PROPN   NE  Case=Nom|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing 1   appos   _   ***NE=PER_23***|Morph=nsf

> 3 Wedemeier   Wedemeier   PROPN   NE  Case=Nom|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing 2   flat    _   SpaceAfter=No|***NE=PER_23***|Morph=nsf

And I would like to have

> 2 Ute Ute PROPN   NE  Case=Nom|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing 1   appos   _   ***NE=B-PER***|Morph=nsf

> 3 Wedemeier   Wedemeier   PROPN   NE  Case=Nom|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing 2   flat    _   SpaceAfter=No|***NE=I-PER***|Morph=nsf

I now want to parse over the file, changing all occurring "NE=NamedEntityTag_Number" to IOB (the type isn't important, just each "NE=field_type_number (in the example "NE=PER_23") to (NE=B-PER and NE=I-PER). PER could be any field in in list_of_fields. Therefore, I created a list_of_fields with all named entity tags occurring. Since the conllu file is saved as a text file, I am parsing over a text file. Since not all lines contain named entity tags, I first check, whether a named entity tag is in the line, if so, I check, if the same tag (including the same number) is in the next line, and the line after that etc. This is important: when the next line contains the same annotation with the same number id, it belongs to the same entity, and therefore, the first must be B-PER, whereas the following of that row must be I-PER.

I am trying to use fileinput, just to change the part of the NE's.

Hope someone can help, thanks!

`

```
import fileinput

import re

list_of_fields = ["PER", "ORG", "LOC", "GPE", "OTH"]

with fileinput.FileInput(file, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
    for line in file:
        ne = [annotation for annotation in list_of_fields if (annotation in line)]
        if re.compile(r"^NE="+ne+"\_\d+$") in line:
            if re.compile(r"^NE="+ne+"\_\d+$") in next(line) == re.compile(r"^NE="+ne+"\_\d+$") in line:
                re.sub(r"^NE="+ne+"\_\d+$", r"NE=B-"+ne, line)
                re.sub(r"^NE="+ne+"\_\d+$", r"NE=I-"+ne, next(line))
            else:
                re.sub(r"^NE=" + ne + "\_\d+$", r"NE=B-" + ne, line)`
```

Comment: I don't know anything about this file format but you can't use `next()` while looping over the file because that will exhaust the iterator. Also, it would help if you could provide some inputs and expected outputs that demonstrate the issue you described.

Comment: I adjusted the description from above. I just need to switch all "NE=..." appropriately

Comment: Will each line only have one of the fields you listed? And do the fields' values (e.g. PER_23) always appear in groups that change sequentially throughout the file?

Comment: yes, each line either one NE= or none! And no, the numbers do not change sequentially. So it could be, that two lines (FC Bayern München) would be ORG_74, ORG_74 and ORG_74 (as they build one unit, therefore the same number, and therefore denoted as ORG (organization)). However, it could be, that the next appearance of ORG could be ORG_215, and not ORG_75. In the new annotation style, the first ORG_74 (FC), would be  B-ORG, Bayern I-ORG, and München I-ORG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the last field and last value to compare it across multiple lines. If either differs with the next one, you do the replacement with `B-<field>` and otherwise with `I-<field>`:

```py
import fileinput
import re

list_of_fields = ["PER", "ORG", "LOC", "GPE", "OTH"]
joined_fields = f'({"|".join(list_of_fields)})'
field_pattern = re.compile(f'NE={joined_fields}')
last_field = last_value = None

with fileinput.FileInput(file, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as in_file,
     open('output.txt', 'wt') as out_file:

    for line in in_file:
        matches = re.findall(field_pattern, line)
        if not matches:
            # keep input
            out_file.write(line)
            continue
        field = matches[0] # assuming only one field per line
        start_index = line.find(f'NE={field}')
        end_index = line.find('|', start_index)
        value = re.findall(rf'{field}_(\d+)', line[start_index:end_index])[0]
        if field != last_field or value != last_value:
            replacement = f'B-{field}'
        else:
            replacement = f'I-{field}'
        last_field = field
        last_value = value
        new_line = re.sub(rf'{field}_{value}(-{joined_fields}_\d+)*', replacement, line)
        out_file.write(new_line)
```

EDIT: allowed for multiple fields, using only the first one

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
it is almost correct. However, for word spans like "FC Bayern München" it is now tagged as FC = B-ORG, Bayern = B-ORG, München = I-ORG. It should be, however, FC = B-ORG, Bayern = I-ORG_<number>, München = I-ORG_<number>. But really thank you for that!

Comment: Ohhhh, I see where the errors are. In some cases, as is the case of FC Bayern München, there are two tags, that are separated by a dash. So FC = ORG_128, Bayern = ORG_128-ORG_129, München = ORG_128-ORG_129-GPE_130... I guess I would stick to the first occurring tag, so ORG_128, thereby deleting the rest of the tags. Sorry for that!!

Comment: Could you extend your question with those tricky inputs?

Comment: yes, for some cases, the tag extends to a second tag, that looks like "ORG_128-ORG_129-GPE_130. And for those cases, I only need the first tag, namely I-ORG in this case.

Comment: @darned7 I updated my answer to allow for multiple fields as you've described them